# Strange line in Node.js stacktrace

Tags: node.js

I'm getting a weird stacktrace from my `nodejs` express server:

```
Object.exports.addOne.exports.addTwo (/usr/src/app/utils/request.util.js)
```

*(Rest of the stacktrace was omitted)*

I'm not quite sure what this notation means `(exports.function1.exports.function2)`.
All I do is call `addTwo` function but the line in the stacktrace seems weird and I can't understand what cause this.

**app/utils/request.util.js:**

```
exports.addOne = function() { .. }
exports.addTwo = function() { .. }
```

What does this notation means?

Comment: Add in question `request.util.js` file content. And what error description?